# Using non-ATMEL ARM Cortex M3 with Arduino/MPIDE

Tags: arduino, port, cortex-m

My question is coming from someone that knows more about microcontroller interfacing than the architecture or the toolchain.  I noticed that most if not all Arduino Dev boards are ATMEL based uC's but may have the same architecture as uC's by other manufacturers.  One example of this is the Arduino DUE (ATMEL's SAM3X8E) and TI's TMS470M.

Basically, I want to know how I could get TI's TMS470M to work under the Arduino toolchain?  I've noticed a similar question floating around where the answer was to use MPIDE but without any hint on how to get started.  Could someone outline exactly what I would need to do to make another ARM Cortex M3 work under either the MPIDE or Arduino IDE's?  The more detail the better.

Thank you all for looking!

Comment: dont think that is how it works for the dual processor boards.  for single processor boards that have a full arduino compatible sandbox then you use the sandbox.  for the dual processor ones I assume you use the sandbox for the arduino side then whatever native tools for the other processor...

Comment: I don't believe the TMS470M has two cores but TI's C2000 series processors do.  Really what I'm asking is what file(s) I would need to change to be able to program other Cortex M3's other than the ATMEL ones.